# Find data in other row from data in another row in excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sorting, rows, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet like so:

```
| A    | B | C              |
|------|---|----------------|
| Bob  |   | Mary is Nice   |
| Mary |   | Tim is happy   |
| Tim  |   | Bob is awesome |
```

and I'm trying to use Excel to find the name values in column A and match the content in column C and then match the output in column B like so:

```
| A    | B              | C              |
|------|----------------|----------------|
| Bob  | Bob is awesome | Mary is Nice   |
| Mary | Mary is Nice   | Tim is happy   |
| Tim  | Tim is happy   | Bob is awesome |
```

I'm not sure if there is a formula that can find, match, and sort into column B out of the box. Or if I would need to write a macro. I've been looking and the only thing I can find so far is a match based of a specific value and move it into a seperate worksheet.

I can do this with PHP/MySQL, but that's not the intended result, obviously.

Also, maybe something easier to do within Google Sheets instead?

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX/MATCH with wild cards:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH("*"&A1&"*",C:C,0))
```

OR

VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",C:C,1,FALSE)
```

[image]